# a="hello", b="bye", c=a*b then print c?

Tags: string, multiplication

I came across one question like this

a="hello", b="bye", c=a*b

then what will the anwser of print c?

Comment: What language is that?

Answer (score 3):

That depends on the implementation of the `*` operator on string data types. And that usually depends on the programming language you use. In most statically typed languages I know, this operator is not defined on strings.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, the value of c will be NaN.

Answer (score 0):

It's a trick question, I think. You can't multiply a string with another string. I don't think any language allows this.

Comment: What about operator overloading? Know there is no any logical reason, but still can be an option.